# Is there a way to skip to the end of a WHILE loop in SQL SERVER?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

My code looks like this:

```
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

        IF (@Result = 'S') 

        -- A lot of code


        FETCH NEXT FROM CUR INTO @A

    END 

CLOSE CUR;
DEALLOCATE CUR;
```

I realized I could use a BEGIN END and an ELSE and put the "lot of code" inside there but is there another way that I could do another FETCH and skip to the end of the WHILE?

Comment: An even better question would be, how can I eliminate the loop in the first place? Looping is not efficient in any DBMS and can be avoided in most situations. To directly answer your question you could put an additional condition on your while loop and set the value so that it will fall out of your loop on the next pass. Want to share the code for the body and see if we can eliminate the loop entirely?

Comment: Agree with @Sean, not sure what `A lot of code` does but most of the time you can do the same thing without loops. Anyway, you can use `BREAK` to exit loop, but probably better to have either an additional condition on the `WHILE` or just have a(n additional) `WHERE` clause on the query that populates the cursor.

Comment: @AaronBertrand [But that doesn't mean the cursor loop doesn't sometimes perform way better than expected.](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/running-totals) ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's the [`BREAK` and `CONTINUE` statements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178642.aspx).

You could say:

```
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

        IF (@Result <> 'S') 
        BEGIN
            FETCH NEXT FROM CUR INTO @A;
            CONTINUE;
        END    

        -- A lot of code


        FETCH NEXT FROM CUR INTO @A

    END 

CLOSE CUR;
DEALLOCATE CUR;
```

Comment: Did you mean to put IF (@Result <> 'S')?

Comment: @TabAlleman No, I didn't, but do I think I misunderstood the logic that OP was implying.  Thanks!